# Why to move rvalue reference in a move constructor?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

I've come across the following code:

```
class X {
    std::vector<int> m_v;
public:
    X(std::vector<int>&& v) : m_v(std::move(v)) {

};
```

Parametet v is already an rvalue-reference - so why do we need to apply std::move to it?

Comment: `v` is named object. Every named object is Lvalue. You need to use `move` to cast Lvalue into Rvalue reference, then move constructor of vector can be called.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a move ctor. It is called only for an rvalue, it can't be called for lvalue. How does lvalue arise??

Comment: Consider this code `vector<int> v; X x{move(v)};` so `move(v)` is Rvalue - temporary ? No, it is casted Lvalue into Rvalue reference (strictly it is *Xvalue*). Now in ctor of `X` you can decide if you want to copy `v` or move it: `m_v(v)`  makes copy, but this `m_v(move(v))` moves.

Comment: Well... Let's consider m_v(v). The type of v is std::vector<int>&& i.e. rvalue reference. So m_v(v) uses move-ctor, not copy-ctor. It's pretty obvious, isn't it?

Comment: So try this code and see content of moved vector, it will be untouched. Becasue copy will be made. Just test it.

Comment: [LIVE DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/738c270abc5ded6a). See outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: every named object is *Lvalue*, and even if `v` is reference to Rvalue you need to use `move` to force move ctor to be called.

[From reference - value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

> Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression
>   consisting of its name is an **lvalue** expression;

now your data member `m_v` is vector which contains copy and move constructor.
Next sentences describe which one is called, [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor):

> If both copy and move constructors are provided and no other
>   constructors are viable, overload resolution selects the move
>   constructor if the argument is an rvalue of the same type (an xvalue
>   such as the result of std::move or a prvalue such as a nameless
>   temporary (until C++17)), and selects the copy constructor if the
>   **argument is an lvalue (named object or a function/operator returning**
>   **lvalue reference**).

So when you write:

```
m_v(std::move(v)) // move ctor is called because you are passing Xvalue
```

but in this:

```
m_v(v) // copy ctor is called because v as named object is passed
```